# PHP: Tagging system JOIN statements

Tags: php, mysql

I've implemented an SO-style tagging system to my comics site.

Each comic can have 1 or many tags.

The way I have it set up currently is: There's a comics table, tags table, and a relational comictags table. The query will check if there is a matching comic id and tag id...

```
$sql = 
 "SELECT c.*, t.* 
 FROM comics c 
 INNER JOIN comictags ct ON (c.id = ct.comicID)
 INNER JOIN tags t ON (t.tagid = ct.tagID)
 WHERE ct.tagID IN ('" . implode(', ', $_SESSION['tagids']). "')
". $catquery ." " . $order;
```

[image]

The problem with this is it forces me to add a new entry to comictags table each time I want to add a new tag to a comic id.

Is it possible to have more of this schema:?

`comicid_1:  tagid_1, tagid_2, tagid_3, etc...`

Meaning, I make 1 entry for each comic id, and add a comma separated tag id in the `tagid` field for each tag I want associated.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I would do is drop `ComicsTags.id`. Your primary key is `(imgid,tagid)`, why add more unneeded data?

Comment: @Wrikken where do you mean?

Comment: The `id` column in your `ComicsTags` table. What is it good for? It doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Wrikken I suppose you're right. Maybe I'll need it at some point if I want to delete a specific record based on that ComicTag id? idk haha

Comment: A specific record, of which you know the imgid & tagid? Well, that would be tricky, up to 2 WHERE clauses... Madness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it at the moment is perfectly fine. What you intend to do is not. It violates the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form): each attribute may only contain atomic values.

It is, of course, possible. For example by using a string type for the tagid column. But this complicates a lot of queries and is probably not good for performance.

Comment: Okay, but I don't see how it's atomic in the current state. And I still don't see how adding comma separated tags per comic id would be problematic

Comment: @Growler: imagine querying for all comics having a specific tag-id. It's horrendous if the id's are in 1 column. Multiple bad performing `LIKE`'s are the best you can manage at that point, which requires a full table scan.

Comment: @Growler: I agree with Oswald. Many to many relations, like many tags to one comics and many comics to one tag has been always solved by creating table like yours: ComicsTags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any simpler sql expresion like that:

```
INSERT INTO ComicsTags VALUES (1, 10), (1,20), (1,30);
```

For scripting language level you can write method for model for that table which allow you do that a little simpler:

```
$comicsTags = new ComicsTags();
$tags = array(10, 20,30);
$comicsTags->add(1, $tags);
```